# usage of array session in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I'm kinda lost in using array session in Laravel 4.2. In the documentation, it says `Session::push('user.teams', 'developers');`.

I'm assuming that the `user.team` is the session name then the `developers` is the value. So can I do something like this,

```
Session::push('book.id','1234');
Session::push('book.name','Sample book');
Session::push('book.rating','5');
```

and I'll get it as `$bookName= Session::get('book.name');`

Am I doing this right? or should I just use individual sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you put the array you want, then you push elements to this array by using the `.` symbol

```
$user = ['name'=>'ahmed'];
Session::put('user' , $user);    // Put the array
Session::push('user.age','15');  // Push an Element
//$user = Session::get('user');  // Retrieve all the array
dd(Session::get('user.age'));    // Retrieve only one element
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are doing it right. Array of session in permitted and usable in laravel.

For more information you can have a look at laravel documentation.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session